# Code doesn't work when server response the request

Tags: android, json, server

Recently I'm learning the request and response between server and android .
I try to update a `JSON` file when server responses but I'm failed. the update code doesn't work.

the server code like this:after the code"JSONArray"doesn't work but i don't know why.

```
public class AndroidServerServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6792396567928634227L;

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
        HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String newPassword = request.getParameter("newpassword");
        PrintWriter printWriter = response.getWriter();
        printWriter.print("hello android, password changed");
        printWriter.flush();
        printWriter.close();
        System.out.println(username+"\n"+newPassword);
        ChangePassword(username , newPassword);
        }
        private void ChangePassword(String username , String password){
            try {
                InputStream in = AndroidServerServlet.class
                    .getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/1.json");

                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(in, "UTF-8");  //InputStream → String
                String jsonData = scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").next();
                System.out.println(jsonData);
                scanner.close();
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonData);
                for(int i = 0;i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    if(username.equals(object.getString("username")))
                        object.put("password",password);
                }
                System.out.println(jsonData);
                in.close();
            }catch (Exception e){
                System.out.print("Exception\n");
                }
            }
        }
```

the android code like this:(surbmit is a button)

```
 surbmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    RequestParams requestParams = new RequestParams();
                    requestParams.add("newpassword", "newpassword");
                    requestParams.add("username","test1");
                    new AsyncHttpClient().post("http://10.0.2.2:8080/AndroidServerServlet", requestParams, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                            if(statusCode == 200){
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, new String(responseBody), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "server doesn't response", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

and the json file is this:

```
[{"username":"test1","password":"password1"},
{"username":"test2","password":"password2"},
{"username":"test3","password":"password3"}]
```

When I debug the server code,I found a ERROR:java.long.NoClassDefFoundError:org/json/JSONArray.but I have alerady add that jar in the project,why the error comming?

BTW:I use IntelliJ IDEA + MAVEN + Tomcat to build my server.

the error report:

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONArray
at AndroidServerServlet.ChangePassword(AndroidServerServlet.java:41)
at AndroidServerServlet.doPost(AndroidServerServlet.java:31)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:789)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1437)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I tried to delete the jar I had added and the wrong report is still same as top,proved that I didn't add the jar really,but how can I add it?

Comment: Would recommend using `Retrofit`/`gson` for this...small enough learning curve to use and will make your life much easier!

Comment: is your web service working ?

Comment: actually you are not sending proper request format to server you should send it in json format and you are sending it in request param format.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest using HttpUrlConnection instead of ServletRequest/Response, Scanner, etc ...

Please check this link:https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

You'll find a sample in the **Posting Content** section.